# How to build a decent muscular ripped physique at home by using only bodyweight exercises?

Tags: workout-routines, bodybuilding, body-fat, bodyweight-exercises

[image]

How to build a descent muscular ripped physique at home?

I already know that physique achieved at home cannot be compared to the physique achieved at gym by lifting heave weights. But since gym is far far away from my home, financial instability, I cannot go to the gym. And as I have said I really don't have much money to keep buying dumbbells at home for the sake of progression overload, I am only relied to work on bodyweight exercises at home.

Also, I stay at a place where there is no park around to workout like the bar brothers, so my home is my only gym. I don't want to look like a massive guy (neither it is possible to be super massive by doing only calisthenics) nor do I want to look too much ripped. I just want to look fairly decent and muscular, a little sculpted body to be flaunted in beach and good arms.

To ask the question in much shorter way, I don't wanna get big like Arnold nor do I just want to be super ripped like Bruce Lee. A physique like hollywood actor Taylor Lautner would be my wish.

I am currently 17, weight around 65 kg and height 5'11. Currently, my target is to build a little more mass and look decent physique...a moderate muscular-cum-ripped physique. I dont wanna look skinny! Now I know that Lautner lifted heavy weights for the 30 pound of muscle mass that he gained and I don't have resource to work on weights but I do have some alternatives which i combine with my normal calisthenics.

I need a good routine and diet!  To work by biceps, I take a backpack and do bicep curls and it gives tremendous pump. I do same for tricep skull crushers, lateral rises for shoulders, weighted push ups, weighted pull ups and weighted squats. I use the bag pack to progress the overload and workout in a gym-ush fashion but at home with bodyweight workouts and other alternate sources of weights.

In my current routine, I work my chest and legs thrice a week and arms, shoulders and lats thrice! A good routine would help me a lot and some suggestions. I dont wish to get very big! A physique like taylor lautner is my goal :) The picture of taylor lautner may depict the physique i want almost like!

Answer (score 2):

High intensity interval training (HIIT) is the key and you can do it at home even if you have small space.I recommend buy a nice pullup bar something like this http://www.amazon.com/pull-up-bar/b?ie=UTF8&node=3408471 and work on some sort of workout plan. Have a look at feeletics https://www.freeletics.com/en?gclid=COnEwqHL8MkCFQxvvAodlXcONw and it's availabe in apple store and google play. If it's not free you can still find tons of HIIT exercises or you could build your own program once you get a hang of it.

A typical exercise would be, do one exercise for 45 seconds with high intensity then rest for 15 seconds and move on to the next exercise. Perform 4-5 exercises as one circuit and complete 4-5 circuits.

Sample circuit:-

1. 50 pushups
2. 20 chinups
3. 100 Squats
4. 40 Jump lunges
5. 60 mountain climbers

Comment: Is that within a single circuit or set? How long should the break be between them? How may sets? What types of push-ups and squats?

Comment: This is one set so try doing 4-5 circuit in one training. Once you get a hang of it either increase the reps or try to finish each circuit as quickly as possible with less and less rest. You will hit a plateau after 6-8 weeks as your body will get use to of the routine and will optimize your muscle use and energy used so you will have to change this routine every 4-6 weeks. I can provide you other alternative routine once you get use to of this one.

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak from personal experience, still being a bit on the scrawny side and only recently having started the program, but *[You Are Your Own Gym](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004GTLFNW)* by Mark Lauren comes with a fair amount of recommendations and you can see from his build that it apparently works. He includes both exercise programs and suggestions for diet in the book. There are apparently also apps and videos that he markets.